# Datanode not showing in WEB interface

Tags: hadoop

Newbie on hadoop clusters.
I have setup my two nodes conf as described by M. G. Noll [here](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/).

The datanode has datanode & tasktracker running (jps command show them).

However in the WEB UI I only see one node for the DFS

```
Live Node : 1  
Dead Node : 0
```

Same thing on the MapRed WEB interface.
Datanode logs on slave are just empty.
Did check the network settings both nodes have access to each other on relevant ports.
Did make sure namespaceID are the same.

Comment: Looks like my UFW is blocking the transfers, works fine for starting up/shutting down the cluster though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in the `UFW` settings.

Comment: Please explain what error you faced?